# Passing parameters using POST method

Tags: javascript, c#, post

From `JavaScript` I'm trying to pass some variables to the backend. My code is as follows.

**My requirement:**

I am hoping to send the name, email and description of the user which will definitely come to more that 300 characters and will not comply with a `GET` request. Therefore, how can I send a `POST` request with these parameters. Can someone help me out.

Note: My backend is in `C#`

```
window.location.href = "/Account/New?fullname=". $data.fullName;
```

Comment: `"/Account/New?fullname="+$data.fullName;` use `+` instead of `.` to concate.

Comment: Reason for the downvote ?

Comment: get request is actually 'a bit' more then 300 characters, unless you are trying to be safe vs. network boxes. then your limit is 255. Anyways,  depending on the library/framework of choice, the answer will be different. In vanilla javascript you can read here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest]. Btw, for 4+k rep your question is somewhat poorly researched.

Comment: I believe the reason for downvote is that googling this issue will produce tons of results

Answer (score 2):

By using `window.location` you are sending the parameters by the URL - which means they are sent by a `GET` method and not by `POST`.

To send data to the server using `POST` method, you'll have to either send it by a form which is defined with `method="post"` or, if you don't want to create a form element, by an `AJAX XMLHttpRequest` request.

I would suggest, for learning and simplicity, to start with a simple form, such as:

```
<form action="your-page-after-submittion.html" method="post">
   <p>Your full name: <input type="text" name="fullname" /><br />
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>

   <p>Your message:<br />
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

   <p><input type="submit" value="Send the from"></p>
</form>
```

Or if you want an AJAX request, you can use the following:

```
//prepare your data values to be sent in the request
var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

//create an XMLHttpRequest                  
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

//submit the request to your desired page (user will not be redirected, as this is AJAX request                             
xmlhttp.open("POST","your-page-after-submittion.html",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fullname="+fullname+"&email="+email+"&message="+message);
```

Comment: It gives me a server 500 error and the view doesn't get redirected.

Comment: Exact error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Error occurs at `xmlhttp.send(...)`

Comment: HTTP error 500 means you have some sort of an error on the server side. It is not an error generated in the client. Read more about it [here](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938). Try debugging the server side code, check the data from the request arrives to the server.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a form and submit it via JavaScript by doing the following:

```
function submitFullName(fullName, destination)
{

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var input1 = document.createElement("input"); 

    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = destination;   

    input1.value=fullName;
    input1.name="fullname";
    form.appendChild(input1);  

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
```

@VladimirM made a good point, you could use a direct XMLHttpRequest to do a POST instead of creating a form object:

```
function submitFullName(fullName, destination)
{

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", destination, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("fullname="+fullName);

}
```

Comment: why creating a form, when you can create POST request?

Comment: @VladimirM Yes. All I want to know is how to create a GET request, without using FORMS

Comment: @Illep you mean "POST"? In any case, I gave a link to a duplicate question in the comment above

Comment: @VladimirM thanks, it's early, having my coffee still.

Comment: Typo. Yes "POST".